# Operator precedence error in PHP (AND comparison)

Tags: php, operator-precedence

In my code I have this comparison:

```
$check_iter_C_sfavorito = ($tipo_iter_sfavorito[$id_loop][$k_tg] == 'C') AND (!(abs(@$delta_salto_check_sfavorito) < 0.001));
```

which result as true even when:

```
($tipo_iter_sfavorito[$id_loop][$k_tg] == 'C') ====>>>> is true
```

and

```
(!(abs(@$delta_salto_check_sfavorito) < 0.001)) ====>>>> is false
```

While it is OK if I use the operator "&&" instead of "AND", PHP operator precedence means this should not give this error, because of parentheses!

---

Thanks for the quick answers to both the "Mar* B*". I changed the code as follows:

```
$check_iter_C_sfavorito = (($tipo_iter_sfavorito[$id_loop][$k_tg] == 'C') AND (!(abs(@$delta_salto_check_sfavorito) < 0.001)));
```

... and it is OK!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Equivalent of

```
($check_iter_C_sfavorito = ($tipo_iter_sfavorito[$id_loop][$k_tg] == 'C')) AND (!(abs(@$delta_salto_check_sfavorito) < 0.001));
```

because AND has lower precedence than the assignment (=)

Comment: Only by a few seconds, and I didn't give such a full description as Marc

Answer (score 1):

It's directly specified in the documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

`and` and `or` bind at LOWER precedence than `=`, so your statement with `and` is seen as

```
($foo = 'bar') AND 'baz';
```

Remember that in PHP, the result of an assignment is the value being assigned. This is how the standard "check for db failure" code works:

```
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(msyql_error());
```

because `or` binds lower than `=`, the statement is parsed as:

```
($result = mysql_query($sql)) or die(mysql_error());
```

If the DB query fails, it returns false, which gets assigned to $result. The result of that assignment is also false, which gets `or`ed with the die cal, causing the script to abort. If the query SUCCEEDS it returns a non-false value (the statement handle), and the `or` never kicks in because of boolean shortcircuiting.